# Windows Identity Framework on ASP.NET MVC - how to authorize user per action basis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, wif, windows-identity

Windows Identity Framework on ASP.NET MVC - how to authorize user per action basis?

Like:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Instead of the whole site level security as is the default WIF site integration behaviour?

**UPDATE:**
Maybe should the question goes like, how to allow anonymous users to access the site too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as it turns out, *authorization* element has to be properly set in web.config.

Default is something like:

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Which simply mean deny all anonymous users.

But in MVC it should be like:

```
    <authorization>
        <!--<deny users="?" />-->
    </authorization>
```

Which mean allow all users, and leave application to handle the authentication.

So that mean default WIF setting have to be reverted:

From:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

To something like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

That so, per action authorization in MVC works. Nice. :)

More on Authorization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are able to configure site authentication model in Web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Yes I am aware of that settings, but how does this solve my problem? If I set the mode="Form" it also want authentication at the site level ...